# Settings up Azure Team Services build to deploy to onprem server

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, tfs

We are in the process of moving our onprem TFS isntallation to Azure Team Services. It's time to setup the builds. I have seen several articles about configuring Azure TFS builds to deploy from Azure Team Services to an Azure server. How do you setup the Azure Team Services TFS build to deploy to a server that is onprem? (we have setup Team Services repositories as GIT)+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of many options however to get started you will need a machine running at least 1 instance of the build/release agent (an "automation" agent) deployed on premise (presumably joined to your domain as well).  That agent can the be used for Release workflows to deploy your applications.  [VSTS documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/other-servers/net-to-vm) provides a sample for this.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. It sounds good. Let me give it a shot.